# How to render events by drop, full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using fullCalendar Scheduler and I am trying to render events based on the place that they are dropped.

So if I drop the event between two other events it should render there and not always at the end of the calendar. I have the drop code here:

```
drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) {
                console.log("droped");
                var employers = $("#employee_ids").val();
                var emp = [];
                     $('#external-events .fc-event.isOrNotselected').each(function() {
                         var user = $(this)[0].attributes.id.value;
                         var dropedUserId = $(this).context.attributes["data-resourceid"].value;
                         emp.push(dropedUserId);
                         employers = $("#employee_ids").val(emp);
                         [dropedUserId.split('_').length - 1];
                       $('#employee_ids').val(JSON.stringify(sys.workersArray));
                         var fullname = $("#" + user).find(".fullName").text();
                         $('#fullName').val(fullname);
                         $('#user_id').val($("#" + user + " .user_id").text());
                         var profesion = $("#" + user + " .profesion").text();
                         var photoOnDropShift = $(this).find(".innerAvatarUserLeft img").attr('src');
                         $('#profesion').val(profesion);
                         $(".placeholderForMoreWOrkers ").append(
                             '<div class="employerObj" id="emp_' + dropedUserId + '">' +
                             '<ul class="dropDataUlEmployers" data-id="' + dropedUserId + '">' +
                             '<li class="imageOnDropEmp"><img src="' + photoOnDropShift + '" width="30px" style="border-radius: 50%"></li>' +
                             '<li class="user_nameHere" id="uname_here_head">' + fullname + '</li>' +
                             '<li class="remEmp"><p class="removeFunctionEmployers" onclick=sys.deleteEmployer("#emp_' + dropedUserId + '",0)><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></p></li>' +
                             '</ul>' +
                             '</div>'
                         );
                     });
}
```

Then it opens a modal where I fill in some information, but the main thing I want is to order the event based on where I drop it.
the code above is executed on drop , the event whose place is taken should not be removed , it should stay there , and with event overlap how am i suppose to do that? the problem that I have is that when I add an event I save it in my database and on success I refetch the calendar events and it should stay on the place that  I dropped and allways event should render based on where are dropped, kind of sorting or something , I use events as users , so if I set one users working day on monday,wednesday and friday , it renders the event in different positions noth in the same row

Comment: "if I drop the event between two other events it should render there"...you mean you want to move the other events out of the way (e.g. shift their start times)? Or they should overlap? Does your calendar allow overlaps? It's not clear. What exact issue are you facing? You've told us what you want,but not what your problem is currently.

Comment: So for example if there are three events in the same day, and I want to drop another external event into the same day but in the second place , so between first and second , and after refetching events it should stay there

Comment: Yes you already explained that, but that doesn't answer any of my questions. Read my comment again and respond to the specific points. All you've told me is a too-vague aspiration. What I need is more specific detail of the required behaviour, and also to describe the issue you have with your current code.

Comment: @ADyson i need them to switch places, it allows overlaping but the point is with the API , so first i call events than when i want to drop external events it should be saved exactly where I dropped it, am i clear enough or what else you need

Comment: by "switch places" you mean the event whose place it takes should be removed from the calendar (since we're dropping new events, a literal switch of places would mean putting the replaced event off the calendar and onto the list)? What if they merely overlap rather than matching the start/end times exactly? Should they overlap, or the overlapping existing event(s) be time-shifted out of the way? "I need them to switch places" and "it allows overlapping" are a bit contradictory. So no, it's as clear as mud. And  I don't know anything about your API, you never mentioned that, what's your point?

Comment: And lastly you still forgot to tell me your **problem**. There's lots of code above. Presumably its intention is to implement this dropping of events? So, what's the issue with it? What does it do? What does it not do? What errors or unexpected behaviour do you experience when trying to do this? Don't forget I cannot read your screen, your mind or your documentation.

Comment: the code above is executed on drop , the event whose place is taken should not be removed , it should stay there , and with event overlap how am i suppose to do that? the problem that I have is that when I add an event I save it in my database and on success I refetch the calendar events and it should stay on the place that  I dropped and allways event should render based on where are dropped, kind of sorting or something , I use events as users , so if I set one users working day on monday,wednesday and friday , it renders the event in different positions noth in the same row

Comment: "the event whose place is taken should not be removed , it should stay there". So now you're saying the opposite of "switch places" which you mentioned before. Please make your mind up. I am beginning to think you don't actually know what you want and haven't really thought it through.

Comment: you asked if the event should be removed, so I answered it should not be removed from calendar

Comment: " the problem that I have is "...what you describe is not a _problem_. You are describing simply _what you want_. That is not the same as having a problem. Have you written any code for that, or not? If not, the problem is that you haven't written any code yet. When you have some code to fix, we can fix it. Now...is the code above in the question part of your attempt to meet your requirement, or not? If not, why did you show it? If it is, tell me what is does now, and what you want it to do instead? You still haven't done that.

Comment: "you asked if the event should be removed, so I answered it should not be removed from calendar"...yes but a) that's the opposite of what you said before, and b) you haven't explained what should happen to it instead. You say the calendar allows overlaps, so right now it should simply place the events next to each other, yes? Or no? Again...it's not clear. Nothing is clear. This is what makes me think you haven't actually thought about all your requirements.

Comment: So...I'll give you a while to edit your question so that an answer with some code could actually be written. If it's still not clear, I can find another question which is answerable instead. I've tried to get information from you but you don't seem to understand what kind of detailed information is required in order to write a working computer program. All eventualities have to be covered, in exact detail. Give worked examples with actual specific event data, if it helps. Phrases like "sorting or something" (from your comments above) are vague and cannot be implemented in code.

Comment: yes it is related to my attempt, how am  I suppose to write something that I need help from you guys , if I would know I wouldn't ask , how to render an event that is all that I am asking, I am not asking you to solve my problem , just to guide me through this

Comment: Well it's a Q&A site...we give answers which solve problems. That's the whole point.

Comment: "how to render an event, that's all I'm asking". No you're not. You're asking something intangible and unclear about positioning the event. Fullcalendar renders the event for you when you drop it, if you set the data correctly. Your description is, yet again, non-specific and insufficiently detailed to offer any help. Sorry but that's how it is. You don't have to know how to write the code, of course not, but you need to at least be able to clearly and unambiguously describe what you want and what your problem is.

Comment: I tried to use eventoverlap but it doesn't function , when I dragg external event into the full calendar with console log I see what it is returning and it allways returns the first event, I dragg the fourth but it displays the first

Comment: eventOverlap: function(stillEvent, movingEvent) {
                console.log("eventoverlap",stillEvent);
            }

Comment: the "stillEvent" is the event which is not moving (i.e. the event already on the calendar). If you want to get details of the event being dragged, log the movingEvent instead.